# Click handler for Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to find out how to implement a click handler for items in a ListView in Android.

I have a layout file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView03lr"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:scrollbars="vertical">  
    <LinearLayout  
         android:id="@+id/Linear03lr"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:orientation="vertical"  
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">  



 <!--Put form controls here-->  
        <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"

 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="400dp" />



         <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousbutton"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "fill_parent"

            android:text="Previous Menu"/>
    </LinearLayout>  
</ScrollView>
```

..and an activity/class that has the following code in the OnCreate() method:

```
 ListView lv1;
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
         lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        // @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(ListRecords.this,"Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         });
```

When I run this code, when I click an item in the ListView, nothing happens.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `ScrollView`, or move the `ListView` outside of the `ScrollView`. Generally, you cannot have scrollable things inside of other scrollable things.